# How do I convert a number to a string without using stdlib.h or string.h?

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my exercise:

> Write a function that receives from the user two strings that show two real numbers (possibly negative),
> And produces a string that contains the integer part of most of the numbers represented by the string. For example,
> Given the string `2356.12` and the string `243.5` the program must create the string `2112.`

```
void addstrings(char *snum1, char *snum2, char *res);
```

I need to create this function, and two more helper functions

```
//  a function that receives a string that represents an actual number and returns the above number (that i succeed)
double stod(char *snum);
```

```
// A function that receives an integer and produces a string representing the number
void itos(long int num, char *snum);
```

that are used in the `addstrings` function.

---

Here is my attempt so far:

```
void addstring(char *snum1, char *snum2, char *res) {
    stod(snum1);
    stod(snum2);

    *res = (long int)(*snum1 + *snum2);
}

double stod(char *snum) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; snum[i] != '\0'; i++)
        res = res * 10 + snum[i] - '0';

    // return result.
    return res;
}

double itos(long int num, char *snum) {
    int i = 0;
    while (num) {
        snum[i++] = (num % 10) + '0';
        num = num / 10;
    }

    return (double)num;
}

int main() {
    char arr1[SIZE + 1];
    char arr2[SIZE + 1];
    char *res = NULL;
    int temp;

    gets(arr1);
    gets(arr2);

    addstring(arr1, arr2, res);

    printf("%d", addstring);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing in the `addstring` function?

Comment: Dosen't say anything about `<stdio.h>`? So why not `snprintf`? ;)

Comment: On a more serious note, never ever use `gets`! It's considered so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that it have even been removed from the C standard. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: how you would do this exrcise using snprintf but must include these two functions.?

Comment: Unrelated (for now) advice: you've got to be real careful with floating-point numbers. What appears to be `2.46` can in fact be `2.45999999994236543652`

Comment: its not my problem , my problem is to implement itos and addstring functions

Comment: `itos` is easier if you start at the right, with the units digit. Once you have that, just `reverse` the temporary. So the int `2804` get transformed to the "temporary" string `"4082"` and reversed into `"2804"`

Comment: how to do that in CODE ?

Comment: Want me to send the solution directly to your teacher? Hint: use `%` (the remainder operator) and `/` to "walk" the digits of the input number.

Comment: i made a update please see it , what i missing in addstring function/

Comment: I have cleaned your question up slightly. Note you have a discrepancy between `addstrings`, plural, in the initial exercise description, and `addstring`, singular, in the code and its description.

Comment: @Benzz `stod(snum1)`, `stod(snum2)`: you're returning a value from `stod()`, but you never use that. Apart from that, I don't think `*res = (long int)(*snum1 + *snum2);` is doing what you think it is doing; plus, you're also dereferencing a NULL pointer (`res`) here.

Comment: how to fix it ?

Comment: You should start by providing a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that compiles without error (preferably treating warnings as errors), or make the focus of the question be about the errors received. Some things to answer: Which headers do you use? If none, where is `printf` defined? What is `SIZE`? What do you expect `printf("%d", addstring);` to do, considering `addstring` is a function? Why do you discard the results of `stod`? No one wants to do your homework, so you must show effort to narrow this to a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your question and your code:

- *Write a function that receives from the user two strings that show two real numbers (possibly negative),* this part is unclear: do you mean the function should read user input and convert it to `double` values?
- *And produces a string that contains the integer part of most of the numbers represented by the string* This is also unclear. From the next phrase, it appears you should output the integral part of the difference of the `double` values.
- `double stod(char *snum);` could be implemented using `sscanf()`. Your version only works for positive integral values.
- `void itos(long int num, char *snum);` could be implemented simply using `sprintf()`.
- in `addstrings` you do not store the return values of `stod()` and instead you add the values of the first characters of the strings and you store that as the first character of the output.
- you should never use `gets()`
- `printf("%d", addstring);` is incorrect: you pass the address of function `addstring` instead of its return value.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double stod(char *snum) {
    double d;
    if (sscanf(snum, "%lf", &d) == 1)
        return d;
    else
        return 0;
}

void itos(long int num, char *snum) {
    sprintf(snum, "%ld.", num);
}

void addstring(char *snum1, char *snum2, char *res) {
    double d1 = stod(snum1);
    double d2 = stod(snum2);
    long int diff = (long int)fabs(d1 - d2);
    itos(diff, res);
}

int main() {
    char arr1[32];
    char arr2[32];
    char res[32];

    if (scanf("%31s%31s", arr1, arr2) == 2) {
        addstring(arr1, arr2, res);
        printf("%s\n", res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Benzz: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.